# Identity of sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm struggling to understand the following derivation where $n$ is a positive integer.

$$
\sum_{\ell=0}^n {n \choose \ell} 2^\ell \log 2^\ell = n \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose \ell} 2^{\ell+1}.
$$
Splitting off the last term of the sum I can see where the $n$ factor comes from but I'm not sure why this changes the binomial coefficient.

Comment: I wonder if there is something missing, try $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: Are you using the base $2$ logarithm?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace with $l$ with $k$ for better readability

$$\log(2^k)=k\cdot\log2$$

and $$k\binom nk=k\cdot\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$